# How to direct call xhml page from ManagedBean based on action method return string without faces-config.xml file

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, managed-bean

### 1. ManagedBean class

```
@Named
public class LoginBean{
    private String username;
    private String password;

    private String userType;

    // setter getter

    public String login() {

        ...
        if(isUserValidate()){
            if(userType.equals("HR"){
                return "HRHOME";
            }

            if(userType.equals("ADMIN"){
                return "ADMINHOME";
            }
            if(userType.equals("MANAGER"){
                return "MANAGERHOME";
            }


        }
        return "FAILURE";
    }
}
```

### 2. xhtml files

```
WebContent\app\common\login.xhtml;
WebContent\app\common\error.xhtml;

WebContent\app\admin\adminHome.xhtml;
WebContent\app\hr\hrHome.xhtml;
....
```

### 3. faces-config.xml

```
<!-- Case 0  for login user  -->
<from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>LOGIN</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/app/common/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>

<!-- Case 1 if login user is from HR -->
<from-view-id>/app/common/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>HRHOME</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/app/hr/hrHome.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>ADMINHOME</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/app/admin/adminHome.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
...
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>FAILURE</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/app/common/error.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

As you see in the above snap code..

The login.xhtml is common for all users, 
based on the logined user validation the result page would be decides.
if user belongs to HR then app/hr/hrHome.xhtml would be redirect
if user belongs to Admin then app/admin/adminHome.xhtml

Requirement :
 I  want to redirect the specific result xhtml page based on the return string of action method login() of LoginBean class  instead of using the xml configuration file faces-config.xml.

**How can I do it using Primefaces with JSF ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
 if (isUserValidate()) {
         return "/WebContent\app\hr\hrHome.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
      } else  if(userType.equals("ADMIN"){ {
         return "/WebContent\app\admin\adminHome.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
     } else if(.......){
      .........
     }else{
          return "/WebContent\app\admin\error.jsf?faces-redirect=true"
     }
```

Comment: Thank you very much **@tsotzolas** Actually I don't want to return such type of string. basically the return type of string would be constant (final) or Enum value. Is there any solution with annotation through which critical part of the url `/WebContent\app\admin\`  can be  passed.

Comment: @Jimmy I can't understand what do you want. what is the critical path?
You want to return only the page that the login method must redirect the user based on the usertype?